# Am I able to track how far a device has moved?

Tags: android, distance, measure

Is it possible to use the sensors in an android device to determine how far the device has moved from it's initial position?

For example, I hit start on my phone app (sets distance to 0), then walk to the other side of my house and click stop (end position) and it returns the total meters traveled. Is it possible to track this using sensors in the phone (not sure if that requires GPS or not??)? If it is, how accurate would it be and how do I go about implementing something like this? Thanks.

Comment: You can use the accelerometer to know if the device is moving and his vector but its not going to be precise.

Comment: You can use Location API. It has a built in function to measure the distance between two point. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double, double, double, double, float[])

Comment: use google location api for this .

Comment: would  Location API be accurate? specially indoor